# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'appendChild')

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to insert a new Div and an img inside that div via JS. I made a Class that i will user later on with a function inside that should be called to use that function and insert the image. When doing this i constantly get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'appendChild')` HTML and JS below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Actividad 3</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="actividad3.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">


<body >
<h2>EXTRAS DISPONIBLES</h2>

    
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
class extra {
    precio = "10€";
    url = "concha_azul.jpeg";
    constructor(precio, url) {
        this.precio = precio;
        this.url = url;
    }
    getHTML = function () {
        console.log("hello");
        var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
        newDiv.id = "x";
        var div = document.getElementById("x");
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = "concha_azul.jpeg";

        div.appendChild(img); 
    }
    
}

let miExtra = new extra();
miExtra.getHTML();
```

Comment: Why do you have this line `var div = document.getElementById("x");` ?? Until you append it to the dom, you cannot get that property.. Try something like this `newDiv.appendChild(img);`..

Answer (score 0):

When you attempt to grab the 'newDiv' element by it's id it doesn't yet exist in the HTML document. You need to append the newDiv element to the page first and then you can retrieve it by it's id...

```
 //Create new div
 var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
 newDiv.id = "x";

 //Add div to html body
 document.body.appendChild(newDiv);

 //Get new div by it's id
 var div = document.getElementById("x");
 var img = document.createElement("img");
 img.src = "concha_azul.jpeg";
 div.appendChild(img);
```

Also to make things more simple you could just do this...

```
 //Create new div
 var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
 newDiv.id = "x";

 //Add div to html body
 document.body.appendChild(newDiv);

 //Add an image element to the div
 var img = document.createElement("img");
 img.src = "concha_azul.jpeg";
 newDiv.appendChild(img);
```

Comment: I've tried this and still get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'appendChild') but now for `document.body.appendChild(newDiv);`

Comment: @SamuelVanBladel Is "actividad3.js" the location of your extra class? If so the body of the page and it's elements haven't loaded yet so the "document.body" will return null. The script will need to go below the body tag.

Comment: Yes it is. I've moved it now in the bottom of the Body tag and it worked. Tried under the body tag but it wasn't allowed. Many many thanks!